# How do i display all the date in x axes

Tags: matlab

I am using Matlab to plot a graph but i am not getting all the date's in x axes. for example first date starts off 21/2/2013 next date continues as 21/2/2012 but it should be 21/2/2013, 24/2/2013 etc... is there a way to accomplish this? This is the syntax i am using for plotting my graph:

```
plot(dates,mean([h,l],2),'--r','LineWidth',2)
```

I am using date as an array, i found out that i can use `Units` but it does not work
Also is there any way i can add a graph side by side so first graph should appear on right side where the second graph should appear on left hand side. Is this to do with GUI or do i am have to position these graph specifically in a greed 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

there is a function for that 
see

http://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/dateaxis.html

also make sure that the "dates" variable, holds the dates not strings (e.g. 744564)

Comment: I dont want to convert date to year, month etc.. i want to place all the date to appear in my x axes. e.g. 01/01/2013, 01/02/2013 not a big gaps between two dates e.g. 01/01/2013, 01/05/2013 etc...From the picture you can see when i zoom in its hard to find out at which date at line is increasing or decreasing

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the tick marks to something custom I believe. Assuming `tickDates` has all of the date values where you want a tick value:

```
plot(dates,mean([h,l],2),'--r','LineWidth',2)
set(gca,'XTicks',tickDates)
```

As far as side by side plotting, you want to use subplots.

```
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(dates,mean([h,l],2),'--r','LineWidth',2)
subplot(2,1,2)
```

For more, see http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/setting-axis-parameters.html